# Symfony2 Doctrine iterate over with while next()

Tags: php, mongodb, loops, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm looking for a **working solution**, to iterate over a [mongodb](/questions/tagged/mongodb) `PersistentCollection` in [symfony2](/questions/tagged/symfony2). Unfortunately this seems not to work? **Symfony ignores** the `next()` function!

```
while (($animal = $zooAnimals->next()) !== false) {

    $color = $animal->getColor();

    print_r($color); die; // Test and die
}

print_r('Where are the animals?'); die; // << Current result
```

Reference: [Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\PersistentCollection](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/mongodb_odm/1.0/class-Doctrine.ODM.MongoDB.PersistentCollection.html)

Comment: What's wrong with `foreach($zooAnimals as $animal)` ?

Comment: @Touki because `$zooAnimals` is not a `array()`! `is_array($zooAnimals); // false`

Comment: So what? Your collection implements [Doctrine\Common\Collection](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.4/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.Collection.html) which implements [IteratorAggregate](http://php.net/iteratoraggregate) which lets you iterate (`foreach`) over an object.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thank you for the enlightening answer below !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not Symfony's *"fault"*. This is a misunderstanding of [how to iterate over an object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php). There are several ways to handle this for your use case. Here are some

## Use a foreach!

Your [`PersistentCollection`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/mongodb_odm/1.0/class-Doctrine.ODM.MongoDB.PersistentCollection.html) implements [`Collection`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.4/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.Collection.html) which implements [`IteratorAggregate`](http://php.net/iteratoraggregate) which implements [`Traversable`](http://php.net/traversable) *(long way heh?)*.
An object which implements interface `Traversable` can be used in a **`foreach`** statement.

`IteratorAggregate` forces you to implement one method `getIterator` which must return an [`Iterator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php). This last also implements `Traversable` interface.

## Usage of an iterator

`Iterator` interface forces your object to declare 5 methods in order to be used by a `foreach`

```
class MyCollection implements Iterator
{
    protected $parameters = array();
    protected $pointer = 0;

    public function add($parameter)
    {
        $this->parameters[] = $parameter;
    }

    /**
     * These methods are needed by Iterator
     */
    public function current()
    {
        return $this->parameters[$this->pointer];
    }

    public function key()
    {
        return $this->pointer;
    }

    public function next()
    {
        $this->pointer++;
    }

    public function rewind()
    {
        $this->pointer = 0;
    }

    public function valid()
    {
        return array_key_exists($this->pointer, $this->parameters);
    }
}
```

You can use any class which implements `Iterator` it like this - <kbd>[**Demo file**](https://eval.in/81015)</kbd>

```
$coll = new MyCollection;
$coll->add('foo');
$coll->add('bar');

foreach ($coll as $key => $parameter) {
    echo $key, ' => ', $parameter, PHP_EOL;
}
```

## Use iterator with a while

In order to use this class *like* a foreach. Methods should be called this way - <kbd>[**Demo file**](https://eval.in/81016)</kbd>

```
$coll->rewind();

while ($coll->valid()) {
    echo $coll->key(), ' => ', $coll->current(), PHP_EOL;
    $coll->next();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Simple solution:

<kbd>1</kbd> Convert your **PersistentCollection** to an array first

```
$zooAnimalsArray = $zooAnimals->toArray();
```

<kbd>2</kbd> Handle the array classically like you would with any PHP arrays.

<kbd>Note</kbd> *This has the advantage of creating code that doesn't depend too much on your database (in case you wish one day to switch to a relational database), you wouldn't have to rewrite everything.*

Answer (score 2):

Works to me!

```
$collection = new ArrayCollection();
$collection->add('Laranja');
$collection->add('Uva');
$collection->add('Morango');

do {
    print_r($collection->current());
} while ($collection->next());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution,

```
$zooAnimals->getIterator();

while ($animal = $zooAnimals->current()) {

    echo $animal->getColor();

    $zooAnimals->next();
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: With `getIterator()` gets a Iterator to iterate over the array of objects, then with `while` loops over the array thanks the Iterator, `current()`get the object of the current position, finally with `next()` you get next object of the array.

Comment: Please edit your answer to contain all explanation